# ArrayList of EditText to SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I develop an app for android.

I have a lot of variables of `EditText` type. I'd like to use a `Button` to save data which was entered by the user. The problem starts when I try to put every `EditText` one by one. 
So I thought about using an `ArrayList`. I read that I can't put an `ArrayList` directly to SharedPreferences. But which way is better to do this? Use a Hash, serializable or one by one? I am a beginner so I don't know which way is better - it means more easy to use but longer.

In this case which I tried in one variable ("m" only) but when I click a Button to save this it goes out from app.

How can I improve this code to work correctly?

This is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";


    EditText m,m1,m2,m3,m00,m11,m22,m33;
    Button button10;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
        final EditText m1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message1);
        final EditText m2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message2);
        final EditText m3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message3);
        final EditText m00 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message00);
        final EditText m11 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message11);
        final EditText m22 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message22);
        final EditText m33 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message33);

        List<EditText> messageLIST = new ArrayList<EditText>(){{
            add(m);
            add(m1);
            add(m2);
            add(m3);
            add(m00);
            add(m11);
            add(m22);
            add(m33);
        }};
        for(int i = 0; i < messageLIST.size(); i++)
        {
            messageLIST.get(i);
        }


        sharedPreferences = getApplication().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String numberValue = sharedPreferences.getString("numberValue", null);
        m.setText(numberValue);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void saveButton(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        m.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplication().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("numberValue", m.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Comment: You did declare EditText already: EditText m,m1,m2,m3,m00,m11,m22,m33;  Remove  - final EditText from lines with findbyid.

Comment: @SergeyNeskoromny Thank you for response. But when I removed this my messageLIST is wrong at now. Lines with add(m) and next one is wrong: 'Variable "m" is accessed from within inner class, need to be declare final.'

Comment: `final EditText m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);` should be `m = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);`, since you declared your `EditText` at the top.

Comment: Remove <final> and <EditText> - you duplicate the declaration. EditText m,m1,m2,m3,m00,m11,m22,m33; - visible in the all scope of you activity!

Comment: @SergeyNeskoromny Thank you. I didn't see this mistake. Now, it's without mistakes but I still think about which way choose to save this data info SharedPreferences by button.

Comment: Make envelope class to hold your input data. Like class User { String name; String surname;}. Populate all this fields. Implement method serialise(). You can use JSON or coma separation. And then implement deserialise method for your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why you need to do this. You can just save comma seperated String for your all edit text values in preferenses.You dont need those lines ..

```
 List<EditText> messageLIST = new ArrayList<EditText>(){{
    add(m);
    add(m1);
    add(m2);
    add(m3);
    add(m00);
    add(m11);
    add(m22);
    add(m33);
}};
for(int i = 0; i < messageLIST.size(); i++)
{
    messageLIST.get(i);
}
```

Just do this

call getText.toString() on each edit text and append it by other value and then save it in a key to your preference

Comment: But in function called saveButton I need to call the same number of variables. I tried this previously and I had a problem with store a data to one variable which stored this.

Comment: That what you are doing . In that case you are just consuming memory. You are creating one extra Collection which is no use of it . The thing you need is only text from each edit text ..

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop, you can create a json string and save it to the sharedprefs like;

```
public void saveToSharedPrefs(List<EditText> messageLIST) {

    JSONArray jsonArrayParent = new JSONArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < messageLIST.size(); i++) {

        String str = messageLIST.get(i).getText().toString().trim();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonChid = new JSONObject();
            jsonChid.put("key", str);
            jsonArrayParent.put(jsonChid.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplication().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("numberValue", jsonArrayParent.toString());
    editor.commit();
}
```

and call this method in your saveButton method like

```
public void saveButton(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    saveToSharedPrefs(messageLIST);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work correctly in Android Studio. I must editet it by program suggestion like this one: 
JSONArray jsonArrayParent = new JSONArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < messageLIST.size(); i++)
        {
           String str =  messageLIST.get(i).getText().toString().trim();
            JSONObject jsonChid = null;
            try {
                jsonChid = new JSONObject(str);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            jsonArrayParent.put(jsonChid);
        }

Comment: Sorry, @gryzek, can you try again with the edited block?

Comment: Now, it's without any mistakes. But now, how can I use this in  button function to save entered data?

Comment: Edited the answer again @gryzek, declare messageLIST as a global object in your class.

Comment: I did what you said @dgngulcan but it doesn't work. When I run this, it works without saving.
To one variable I used 'editor.commit' to save a data.
In line <List><EditText>messageLIST <- I have info by program that 'messageLIST is updated but never queried'

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create a `Map<String, EditText>()`. Add all your EditText's to the `Map` using `put("Your key value", yourEditText)`. When you want to store it to `SharedPreferences` do this:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplication().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
 for(Map.Entry<String, EditText> entry : map.entrySet()){
    editor.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().getText().toString();
 }
 editor.commit();
```